# catching celery connection errors

Tags: python, redis, celery

I have a problem with celery and redis as broker. After some time my celery workers stop working and give me messages "Consumer: connection refused too many open files. Trying again in 32 seconds". I know for this error, even it is trying to connect to redis in 32 second it cannot connect to it, everything I should do is to restart worker. But how to catch this error so i can handle it. All i can see is printing error messages in console.

I am using task.prerun, task.postrun and task.failure but no one is called during error messages are printed. So I think something internal is happening into celery.
Is there some kind of celery redis listener where I can handle this error and restart worker.

Comment: Which version of celery are you using, you should check out heartbeat settings, by default, celery will recover the connection.

Comment: I have 3.0.12 version. I solve problem by changing broker, I used rabbitmq instead redis. I think the problem is maybe into kombu for redis, but i was time limited, so i couldn't go very deeply into researching.

But I really want to know is there some callback where I can get all unhandled exceptions in celery.